# Google Drive sync client causing Hard Faults on Windows Server 2008 and using lots of memory

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, g-suite, google

I am using the Resource Monitor in Windows Server 2008 and looking at the Memory usage details.  In particular, I am noticing that the googledrivesync.exe process is running at a rate of about 2,600 Hard Faults/min.  Not only that, but the amount of Used Physical Memory is at 94%, most of which is from the googledrivesync.exe.

It is well-known on the inter-webs that the Goole Drive sync client is a memory hog, so perhaps if I increase the amount of physical RAM on the server this will lower the percentage use of Physical Memory, but that does not explain why Google Drive uses up so much memory in the first place.  Also, what's the deal with the 2,600 Hard Faults/min ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why are you using google drive sync on a server?

Comment: Good question.  Not really sure.  It is a testing server, and I am just experimenting to see if I can use Google Drive Sync reliably on this machine to backup certain files.  Is that not a good thing to be doing?

Comment: Google Drive Sync is not a backup. If you delete a file somewhere, it will be deleted on all clients that sync with drive. That's the exact opposite definition of a backup.

Answer (score 2):

> It is well-known on the inter-webs that the Goole Drive sync client is a memory hog, so perhaps if I increase the amount of physical RAM on the server this will lower the percentage use of Physical Memory, but that does not explain why Google Drive uses up so much memory in the first place.

You'll have to ask a Google Drive dev why this is the case.

> Also, what's the deal with the 2,600 Hard Faults/min ?

That means that 2,600 times per minute, a memory page is requested that is no longer in physical RAM. It must be accesses from the pagefile on disk, which is obviously slower than RAM. This occurs because the working set for Google Drive Sync is forcing everything else out of memory to disk.

Comment: Thanks MDMarra.  I think I understand what you are telling me.  Are you saying that because Google Drive is sucking up all the memory, this is causing a memory page(s) to be written to disk?  I guess the only way to resolve this will be to stop using Google Drive on this server. . .

Comment: Or to add enough RAM to accommodate google drive and your other applications

Comment: But aren't there limits with respect to RAM if I am running 32-bit Windows Server 2008?  There is 9GB RAM in the machine, but as the image shows, it seems to be running at 94% Used Physical Memory.  I  guess that not all 9GB RAM are being used.

Comment: 4GB is the most that can be addressed without PAE in that case.

Comment: Looking at your processes, it seems like you have google drive, Dropbox, MySQL, and others running. This isn't a production server, is it?

Comment: nope, this is me branching out from being a lawyer, and trying to learn a few things.  i am testing only to see what works and what doesn't.  really appreciate your input.

Comment: You may be better asking future questions on [SU] then. They're more tailored to learning/power users. Good luck, :)